# custom key sequence in ubuntu mate

Tags: keyboard, shortcuts, mate

I've been looking at custom key shortcuts on Ubuntu, but I haven't seen anything regarding custom  key sequence in Ubuntu Mate 16.04.1.LTS:
Ideally, when I press:

*the windows key + enter,*

this would trigger, in sequence:

*alt+right, control-v, alt-left*

Is this possible? If it's then possible to tweak the timing between these 3 combos, that'd be amazing, but likely unnecessary. I don't know how lofty my dreams can be in Ubuntu Mate...